# Mover o Eliminar Correo ya leído con c#

Tags: c#, .net

a ver si me podríais echar una mano.

Estoy intentando leer unos correos determinados de la bandeja de entrada de un buzón de correo, para después descargar unos ficheros con los link que tiene el contenido del correo. Se va a tener que hacer periódicamente. Tengo hecho y funcionando la lectura de los correos que deseo leer y tratar el contenido.

**Cada vez que haga este proceso no quiero que me lea de nuevo los mismos correos. Por ello, quiero que los correos leídos se eliminen o se muevan a otra carpeta(esto ultimo seria lo ideal).** No consigo encontrar la manera. Estoy utilizando MailKit.

Este es el código de lectura de correos:

```
public static IEnumerable<MimeMessage> ObtenerMensajes()
        {
            string correoEmisor = "correo@correo.com";
            string passEmisor = "XXXXXX";
           
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect("imap.XXXXX.es", 993, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                client.Authenticate(correoEmisor, passEmisor);
                client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                
                var list = new List<MimeMessage>();
               
                var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);
               
                foreach (var uid in uids)
                {
                    var mensaje = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                    mensaje.WriteTo(string.Format("{0}.eml", uid));
                    
                    if (mensaje.Subject.Contains("lo que busco en los correos"))
                    {
                        list.Add(mensaje);
                    } 
                }
                client.Disconnect(true);

                foreach (var correo in list)
                {
                    buscarLink(correo);
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No veo en el código cómo intentas moverlo, o cómo intentas eliminarlos. Nos dices que no lea los correos procesados, qué has intentado para esto? Por favor inserta el código relevante y nos describes el error que recibes.

Comment: Hola Arriel.
Este es el código de lectura de correos. la parte de Mover o eliminar no lo tengo por que no se alguna funcionalidad que me haga alguna de estas acciones. yo deduzco que después de leer el correo y guardarlo en una lista (como lo tengo) acceda al correo para hacer la función con los parámetros del correo a realizar. O bien cuando leo el correo, hacerlo de tal manera que me elimine automáticamente, en Pop3 creo que lo hace así. pero yo quiero hacerlo con  Imap. @Arriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Averigüé cómo mover y eliminar.

Cuando abres la conexión tienes que hacerlo utilizando

```
client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Para eliminar

```
client.Inbox.AddFlags(uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, silent: true);
```

Para mover

```
 //abrir carpeta
    var subCarpeta = client.GetFolder("Carpeta");
 //mover a carpeta abierta
    client.Inbox.MoveTo(uid, subCarpeta);
```

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que hayas encontrado solución! No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.